# Logman - Monitor single process handle count

Tags: windows, perfmon, logman

I am attempting to monitor the Handle Count of a single Process using logman.  I am able to monitor may different counters but cannot seem to get the Process counter to filter down to the single process I am looking for.  These are our logman commands

```
logman create counter BASELINE -f bincirc -max 2000 -si 15 -o "d:\temp\logman" -cf "d:\temp\counters.txt"
logman start BASELINE
```

this is the counters.txt file

```
"\Memory\Available MBytes"
"\Memory\Pool Nonpaged Bytes"
"\Memory\Pool Paged Bytes"
"\Process(*)\Handle Count"
"\Process(*)\Thread Count"
"\Process(WaWorkerHost)\Handle Count"
"\Process(WaWorkerHost)\Thread Count"
```

I have run this in a normal and admin command prompt.  I get my memory counters but only the Handle Counters for all processes appear.

Answer (score 0):

While writing this up I tried one more thing.  If you remove the Process(*) options then it will gather Thread and Handle Count for just the WaWorkerHost Process.  This counters file works fine.

```
"\Memory\Available MBytes"
"\Memory\Pool Nonpaged Bytes"
"\Memory\Pool Paged Bytes"
"\Process(WaWorkerHost)\Handle Count"
"\Process(WaWorkerHost)\Thread Count"
```